Why is SQLite3 returning one more than the actual number of occurrences of a value?
I encountered an unexpected discrepancy while working on a statistics problem using SQLite3. I have a dataset from a CSV file containing seasonal energy efficiency ratios (SEER). My objective was to find the number of occurrences of values greater than or equal to 21.
Here is the data from my .csv file:



SEER




24


40


26


32


13


26


26


28


29


17


25


10


23


22


13


31


31


36


25


27


35


34


17


39


18


21


23


22


26


31


26


25


22


21


34


26


29


24


27


27


24


30


38


31


32


9


26


19


24


29


28


26


19


29


39


26


30


32


28


30


22


25


27


29


24


30


29


20


30


25


26


29


27


25


20


18


15


25


23


27


23


27


24


28


27


40


27


12


30


24


34


33


29


22


40


32


27


35


23


39



I attempted to solve this using SQLite3 with the following queries:
sqlite3 heat_data.db
.mode csv
.import ex02-115heat.csv heat
.schema
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM heat WHERE SEER >= 21;

That last query returned 87. To verify this result was correct (and since I am very inexperienced with SQL), I used Excel's 'COUNTIF' function, expecting it to return 87 as well. Surprisingly, Excel returned 86. Doubting the discrepancy, I manually counted the occurrences and indeed found 86.
I then consulted with ChatGPT, which also confirmed the count as 86.
I'm puzzled by this inconsistency. Are there any issues with my SQL queries or could there be another explanation for this discrepancy?

This depends on data type. If SEER is TEXT type, then "9" >= "21".

Off the top of my head, if the data in the SEER column be numbers with decimal components, then it could explain your observations.  For example, the SEER value 21.00001 might render as 21 in a select query, but be counted as a match in the comparison SEER > 21.
